# Scroll inner box relative to outer box based on mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

looking to slide an inner div based on percentage of mouse position over outer div.
inner div should translateX in percentage based on mouse over the outer div.

outer div is variable width based on screen size 90% of, Inner div  size depends whats added in it at any time.

[image: picture of sliding divs]

```
   // mousePointer = outer div
    mousePointer.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

    var x = $('#slider').width();   // inner div
    var q = $(this).offset()        //  outer div
    var z = Math.floor((e.pageX - q.left ));  // formular not working


     slider.style.transform = 'translateX(' + -z/x*100 + '%)';  // out put is not reliable
 })
```

I have totally forgot how to handle this...